# Statistical test for cross-correlation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-correlation, randomness

Is there any statistical test to determine that two sequence of numbers (e.g. numbers generated by uniform pseudorandom number generators) have a good cross-correlation (close to zero for all lags) with a desired significance level?
(The ideal case in some applications is zero-cross correlation)

I've found some tests for randomness (like NIST and TestU01) but didn't find any test for cross-correlation or auto-correlation.

Answer (score 3):

For auto-correlation, one can use the Box-Cox or variations (e.g. Ljung–Box) to test if any number of auto-correlations are jointly significant. The basis of these tests is that some weighted sum of square auto-correlations is roughly distributed Chi-Squared.

For joint tests of cross-correlations, you can a statistic (e.g. the mean/cum of the correlations), and just bootstrap to obtain standard errors/p-values to carry out the inference. The advantage of bootstrapping is that you don't need to derive the asymptotic distributions.

The following simple Matlab code illustrates what I am suggesting:

```
% Generate data: x and data are correlated at lag 1 and random lag
x               = randn(1000,1);
data            = x;
lagrand         = randi(1000,1);
lagnx           = lag(x,lagrand);
for ii = 1:99
   data        = [data,lag(x,ii)];
end   
y               = 0.5*x+0.5*lagnx + randn(1000,1);
% Cross-correlations, rolling average corr, cumulative corr
n               = 1:size(data,2);
corrs           = corr(y,data,'rows','pairwise');
avgcorr         = cumsum(corrs)./n;
cumcorr         = cumsum(corrs);
% Try to bootstrap the rolling average estimates 
bootsamples     = bootstrp(999,@(bootdata) 
cumsum(corr(y,bootdata,'rows','pairwise'))./(1:size(bootdata,2)),data);
StdErr          = nanstd(bootsamples);
% Try to bootstrap the cumulative sum estimates 
bootsamplescumsum       = bootstrp(999,@(bootdata) 
cumsum(corr(y,bootdata,'rows','pairwise')),data);
StdErrcumsum            = nanstd(bootsamplescumsum);

% Figure showing data,cross-correlations,avg,sum,errors
figure;
subplot(2,2,1);
plot(data)
hold on;
plot(y); 
legend('x','data');
hold off;
subplot(2,2,2);
bar(corrs);
hold on;
plot(avgcorr)
plot(cumcorr)
hold off;
legend('Cross-correlations','Rolling Average','Cumulative Sum');
subplot(2,2,3);
bar(corrs);
hold on;
plot(avgcorr) 
plot(avgcorr+2*StdErr,'-r');
plot(avgcorr-2*StdErr,'-r');
hold off;
legend('Cross-correlations','Rolling Average','95% Conf. Int.');
subplot(2,2,4);
bar(corrs);
hold on;
plot(cumcorr)
plot(cumcorr+2*StdErrcumsum,'-r');
plot(cumcorr-2*StdErrcumsum,'-r');
hold off;
legend('Cross-correlations','Cumulative Sum','95% Conf. Int.');
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, good answers attract more votes and acceptance and will provide a bit more context and explanation beyond simply stating a suggestion. Why are your suggestions good? What assumptions might be relevant? see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for advice on good answers